# Reset all select dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have have a function that gets called by onbeforeunload. Within I wish to reset all the dropdowns but I cannot find the right method to reset them back to the 0 value.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function displaymessage() {
            document.getElementsByTagName('select').value = 1;
            //or
            document.getElementsByTagName('select').options.length = 0;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="displaymessage()" />
    </form>

    <select name="data[Rate][15][12][num_rooms]" id="r15ro12">
        <option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1 Rooms</option>
        <option value="2">2 Rooms</option><option value="3">3 Rooms</option><option value="4">4 Rooms</option>
        <option value="5">5 Rooms</option><option value="6">6 Rooms</option><option value="7">7 Rooms</option>
        <option value="8">8 Rooms</option><option value="9">9 Rooms</option>
    </select>

    <select name="data[Rate][15][12][num_rooms]" id="r15ro12">
        <option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1 Rooms</option>
        <option value="2">2 Rooms</option><option value="3">3 Rooms</option><option value="4">4 Rooms</option>
        <option value="5">5 Rooms</option><option value="6">6 Rooms</option><option value="7">7 Rooms</option>
        <option value="8">8 Rooms</option><option value="9">9 Rooms</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should not have more than one element with the same `name` or `id` as `#r15ro12` and all your form elements (`input`, `select` etc) should be inside the `form`.

Comment: I just did a quick copy and paste for example, I dont have it in my code, thanks for the feedback, cheers

Comment: Ok, that´s great! Also wondering why one would want to reset the selections on `unload`? (assuming you´re closing a popup window)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
function displaymessage() {
    $("select").each(function() { this.selectedIndex = 0 });
}
```

this selects the first option (not necessarily having value = 0)

Comment: Thanks Fabrizio for the help, but it did not work, it looks right to me

Comment: Keith, above code will work only if you have included the jQuery library.

Comment: Thanks, I had included but an old version, works great now. cheers

Answer (score 9):

Here´s a way to select the first option in all `select`s using native JavaScript;

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    elements[i].selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

...but jQuery is very handy and makes most things much easier.

Answer (score 4):

How about something like:

```
$(window).unload(function () {
    $("select").val("0");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

With raw javascript code, we can do the following,

```
elements = document.getElementsByTagName("select")
for(i=0; i < elements.length ; i++){
 elements[i].selectedIndex= 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function displaymessage() {
    $("select").val("0");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should not use the same name/id for the different tag. It should be  unique for each tag.

In the tag  call the function like,

Then alter ur fun like
    function displaymessage() {
    var x= document.getElementsByTagName('select');
    for(var i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
              document.getElementById(x[i].id).options[0].selected = "0";
        }
    }

Answer (score 1):

Yet Another Way

```
$('select option:first-child').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8pcaT/)

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery solutions I have seen so far don't take into account to remove the previous `selected` attribute if one exists, hence I believe that this extra step is required:

```
$("#myControlId").find("select").each(function (index) {
        var ctrl=$(this);       
        if (ctrl.children().length > 0) {
            $(ctrl.children()).each(function(index) {
                if (index===0) $(this).attr('selected', 'selected'); 
                else $(this).removeAttr('selected');
            });
        }
});
```

This solution only keeps one `selected` attribute in the first option and removes all the others (if applicable).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$( 'select' ).each( function () {
    if ( $( this ).children().length > 0 ) {
        $( $( this ).children()[0] ).attr( 'selected', 'selected' );
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#dropDownListID').val("");

or

$('#dropDownListID').val("0");